# Practical way to share 15GB of files with distributed users on cable connections

Tags: networking, sync, samba, dropbox, nfs

I am working with a company of 7 employees distributed throughout the U.S., each with basic cable internet connections, who need to share about 15 GB of thousands of documents (mostly Word and PDF files). Solutions we have tried include:

- Dropbox (too slow to sync; also, folder structures are not synced across all shares)
- An NFS share hosted on an Amazon EC2 instance (lag is too great in saving documents, especially large Word documents)
- BitTorrent Sync (SUPER fast, but has serious bugs that have caused data loss)

Is there a practical way to share the documents, given constraints regarding network speed?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try out: http://mega.co.nz - it allows syncing of 50GB on the free tier, allows sharing links and guest users and things of that nature. It seems like it would fit your needs.

I have used this service. It syncs folders/structures across all shares, is not buggy like BitTorrent Sync, and has the benefit of being both Free and, depending on how they go about utilizing it, should still be faster to save than the EC2 NFS share.

Comment: Have you personally used it or are you just aware of the service?  Can you elaborate on how it might address the identified issues (like speed, folder structures, data integrity)?  How is this different/better than the services already tried?

Comment: Yes, I have used this service. It syncs folders/structures across all shares, not buggy like BitTorrent Sync, and has the benefit of being both Free and, depending on how they go about utilizing it, should still be faster to save than the EC2 NFS share.